# What are the effects on an opponent's wand with Expelliarmus?

Tags: harry-potter

Does hitting someone's wand with Expelliarmus leave a burn mark on the wand or make the opponent's wand hot to touch?

For example, if someone cast Expelliarmus at my wand and I obviously dropped the wand due to the spells effect and then if I was to then "grab the wand" which hath been forcefully removed from my hand "would it be too hot to touch"? Or would the temperature of my wand not be affected by Expelliarmus?

Answer (score 1):

Expelliarmus does not affect the wand itself at all. It kind of "knocks" it out of the hand of your opponent and -usually- makes it fly towards you and you can catch it.

> Hermione, however, was too quick for him.
>   “Expelliarmus!”
>   Mundungus’s wand soared into the air, and Hermione caught it.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11: The bribe</sub>

As you can see in this randomly chosen example: Hermione simply caught the wand... We see a lot of these examples in the books and none of them hints to any effect on the wand.

Just one additional -irrelevant- piece of information: Expelliarmus is the "disarming- charm" and can be used to remove any kind of weapon from your opponent’s hand...

Answer (score 0):

The Expelliarmus spell is not only a spell to throw away the wand of an opponent but also any kind of weapon.

The name of the spell is made of "Expell" and "armed".
You litterraly expell the weapon of your opponent.

What can make us think about heat wave is the red light that appears when you use the spell. But even if a wand can magicaly survive an hot temperature because it's a magical weapon, I'm not sure that regular muggles weapons could survive.

So as long as expelliarmus doesn't destroy regular weapons, it should be a moving spell like Accio or Wingardium Leviosa but at a scale of speed that the hand can't handled the movement and drop the weapon as it goes far away from its user.

It can be confirmed by the fact that sometimes wizards are also thrown away by the spell with their wands.

Comment: what happens if you use Expelliarmus on an opponent that does not hold anything in his hands?

Comment: this has been [asked before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168736/what-would-happen-if-one-was-to-cast-expelliarmus-on-someone-without-a-wand?rq=1)